# Facebook sdk for api marketing. Issue with v2.9

Tags: facebook, facebook-ads-api

I'm trying to get budget per day and started with getting list of campaigns.
I followed the instructions here https://developers.facebook.com/docs/marketing-api/sdks , but when it reaches this line

```
$my_adaccount = $me->getAdAccounts()->current();
```

It says:
Fatal error: Uncaught FacebookAds\Http\Exception\AuthorizationException: (#2635) You are calling a deprecated version of the Ads API. Please update to the latest version: v2.9. in /home/jane/projects/facebook/vendor/facebook/php-ads-sdk/src/FacebookAds/Http/Exception/RequestException.php:163

So I updated to v2.9 but then it says that 
FacebookAds\Object\AdUser is not found. I added this class and other missing classes from v2.5 and it worked.

But there is another class missing, like `use FacebookAds\Object\AdCampaign;`

So the question is how can I install facebook sdk v2.9 with all classes, that needed? Like AdUser and AdCampaign?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Many of the objects have been renamed to remove `Ad` from the start of their name.

So to fix this, just change `AdUser` to `User`, and `AdCampaign` to `Campaign`.